# Cambiar color de textarea formulario al escribir

Tags: javascript, html

¿alguno podría decirme de que forma puedo hacer que mi textarea en un formulario html, tenga un color de fondo y cuando se empiece escribir sobre ella cambie a blanco?

Un saludo,

Comment: Se puede hacer con asignando el evento click al text area, cuando lo detecte que cambie el color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con CSS es muy fácil ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8dyus1m/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ejemplo</title>
<style>
  .tomatxt{background:#ff6347}
  .tomatxt:focus{background:#fff}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<textarea class="tomatxt" rows="6" cols="40" placeholder="Ejemplo..."></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

La pseudo-clase `:focus` hace un gran trabajo aquí!

Leí tu comentario y reemplacé `id="tomatxt"` (`#tomatxt{}`) con `class="tomatxt"` (`.tomatxt{}`).

Si desea aplicar el estilo a **todas** las `textarea` de su página, entonces también está bien:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ejemplo</title>
<style>
  textarea{background:#ff6347}
  textarea:focus{background:#fff}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<textarea rows="6" cols="40" placeholder="Ejemplo..."></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Para resumir, `#tomatxt{}` asigna el estilo a solo una `textarea`, `.tomatxt{}` a más de una (todas las con `class="tomatxt"`), `textarea{}` a todas.

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)

Answer (score 1):

Este es el text area que en principio aparecerá en color de fondo gris:

```
<textarea rows="6" cols="50">
        Este textarea cambiará de color al detectar el click.
</textarea>
<textarea rows="6" cols="50">
        Este también cambiará de manera dinamica als er recorrido con un for.
</textarea>
```

Con el siguiente Script se detecta cuando se haga click en el text area y entonces cambia el color de fondo a blanco:

```
<script>
      window.onload = function() {
      let elementos = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
      for (var i = 0 ; i < elementos.length; i++) {
          elementos[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
             });
          }
      }
</script>
```

Aunque te recomiendo poner el color gris de fondo en tu archivo css o ponerlo en linea (css en linea).
Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola, funciona, pero solo con un textarea, si le pongo la id a un segundo ya no funciona. ¿Como podría hacerlo para todos?

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez ya te lo he modificado, lo he hecho recorrido con un for, en la variable elementos se almacen todos los elementos que sean "textarea" lo recorro con un for y al elemento recorrido le asigno el evento click y cuando este detecte el evento cambairá de color al elemento que has hecho click.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! Y para ponerlo un poco más dificil. Tambien tengo input y select el formulario. ¿Si quiero hacer lo mismo con los 3 tipos?

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez si te sirvió entonces mi respuesta marcala como solucionada, tendrás que guardarte los elementos tambien  en un array y recorrerlos y hacer lo mismo, el tipo de estilo que le quieras aplicar a cada (this) en los for de los elementos que necesites.